# cursor_factory=None raises an exception

Tags: python, cursor, psycopg2

I wrapped my `psycopg2` connection in `DB` class, and one of the methods is to fetch a cursor. I also added a `cursor_factory` to its parameters, but when using `None` as default value, it raises an error.

```
class DB:

    ... connection code and other stuff ...

    def fetchcursor(self, query, params, in_cursor_factory=None):
        cur = self.conn.cursor(cursor_factory=in_cursor_factory)
        cur.execute(query, params)
        return cur

db = DB()
db.fetchcursor("SELECT * FROM foo", None)
```

The error I get is:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

When I replace `None` with `psycopg2.extras.DictCursor` it works. I want to use `None` as the default, just as the [documentation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/connection.html) says:

```
cursor(name=None, cursor_factory=None, scrollable=None, withhold=False)
```

Comment: As pointed out by Martijn it's a psycopg shortcoming. Fixing it for 2.5.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, it appears that the [`connection.cursor()` implementation](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/blob/03b8b1e97a088788fb92e7be2c2f12cedf1075fd/psycopg/connection_type.c#L53) doesn't handle setting the `cursor_factory` argument to `None` very well.

The code doesn't check for `factory` being set to `Py_None` and calls it regardless. If the keyword argument isn't given `connection.cursor_factory` is used instead, which is, according to the source, set to `extensions.cursor` (e.g. `psycopg2._psycopg.cursor`) by default.

You can replicate this by testing for `None` and using `connection.cursor_factory` instead in that case:

```
def fetchcursor(self, query, params, in_cursor_factory=None):
    if in_cursor_factory is None:
        in_cursor_factory = self.conn.cursor_factory
    cur = self.conn.cursor(cursor_factory=in_cursor_factory)
    cur.execute(query, params)
    return cur
```

This presumes you are using `psycopg` version 2.5 or newer; `connection.cursor_factory` [was added in that version](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/news.html#what-s-new-in-psycopg-2-5).

For previous versions just use `psycopg2._psycopg.cursor` instead of `self.conn.cursor_factory`.

Comment: Thanks, but I get this error: `AttributeError: 'psycopg2._psycopg.connection' object has no attribute 'cursor_factory'`.

Comment: @BartFriederichs: what version of `psycopg2` is this? The source code and the [documentation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/connection.html#connection.cursor_factory) both show the attribute should be there.

Comment: @BartFriederichs: the documentation does state it was introduced with version 2.5.

Comment: @BartFriederichs: investigated some more, substitute `psycopg2._psycopg.cursor` for versions < 2.5.